# Powershell--split CSV into 2 files based on column value

Tags: powershell, csv

I have several large CSV files that I need to split based on a match in one column.

The column is called "Grading Period Title" and there are up to 10 different values.  I want to separate all values of "*Overall*" into overall.CSV file, and all other values to term.CSV and preserve all the other columns of data.

| Grading Period Title | Score |
| --- | --- |
| *Overall* | 5 |
| 22-23 MC T2 | 6 |
| *Overall* | 7 |
| 22-23 T2 | 1 |

I found this code to group and split by all the values, but I can't get it to split overall and all other values into 2 files

#[Splitting a CSV file into multiple files based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934131/splitting-a-csv-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-column-value)

```
$groups = Import-Csv -Path "csvfile.csv" | Group-Object 'Grading Period Title' -eq '*Overall*'

$groups | ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Export-Csv "$($_.Name).csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

> Count Name                      Group
>
> ---
>
> 278 22-23 MC T2
> 71657 *Overall*
> 71275 22-23 T2
> 104 22-23 8th Blk Q2

So they are grouped, but I don't know how to select the Overall group as one file, and the rest as the 2nd file and name them.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To just split it, you can filter with `Where-Object`, for example:

```
# overall group
Import-Csv -Path "csvfile.csv" | 
  Where-Object { $_.'Grading Period Title' -Like '*Overall*' } |
  Export-CSV -Path "overall.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# looks like
Grading Period Title Score
-------------------- -----
Overall              5
Overall              7


# term group
Import-Csv -Path "csvfile.csv" | 
  Where-Object { $_.'Grading Period Title' -NotLike '*Overall*' } |
  Export-CSV -Path "term.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# looks like
Grading Period Title Score
-------------------- -----
22-23 MC T2          6
22-23 T2             1
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the clear answer from **[@Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale)** and do this is one iteration using the [Steppable Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline):

```
Import-Csv .\csvfile.csv |
ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $Overall = { Export-CSV -notype -Path .\Overall.csv }.GetSteppablePipeline()
    $Term    = { Export-CSV -notype -Path .\Term.csv }.GetSteppablePipeline()
    $Overall.Begin($True)
    $Term.Begin($True)
} -Process {
    if ( $_.'Grading Period Title' -Like '*Overall*' ) {
        $Overall.Process($_)
    }
    else {
        $Term.Process($_)
    }

} -End {
    $Overall.End()
    $Term.End()
}
```

For details, see: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/).