# Split csv into multiple files by date

Tags: powershell, csv

i have a CSV File which contains the following data:

PERNR;DATE;TIME;EVENT

I want the lines to be seperated by DATE and for each date a seperate file.

e.g.
10.03.24.csv
11.03.24.csv
12.03.24.csv

Can anyone help me on that one?

Greetings
SL

Comment: Is the date format in the CSV always `MM.dd.yy`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See: [Powershell--split CSV into 2 files based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75327770/1701026). Please also read: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question and copy/paste the source code you are trying to make work into the question.